# What is the smallest number $n$ for which $bb(n)>f_{\epsilon_0}(5)$ is known?

Tags: number-theory, turing-machines, big-numbers

It is known that $bb(23)$>Graham's number (I do not remember exactly, but $bb(21)$ could already be larger).

> But what is the smallest number $n$, such that $bb(n)>f_{\epsilon_0}(5)$ is known ?

Here :

[Milton Green's lower bounds of the busy beaver function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723286/milton-greens-lower-bounds-of-the-busy-beaver-function/736618#736618)

it is mentioned that $\Sigma(41,3)$ is much greater than $f_{\epsilon_0}(5)$, but I am looking for a binary machine.

Comment: Best known for Graham's number is $\Sigma(22)$. I also confirm the result that Deedlit mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wythagoras created an 85-state Turing machine that produced more than $f_{\varepsilon_0}(1907)$ ones, listed [here](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User:Wythagoras/Rado%27s_sigma_function/BB(85)).  I believe it is based on an implementation of the Kirby-Paris hydra.

Comment: Very interesting! +1

Comment: According to the link, $bb(85)$ is even largen than $f_{\epsilon_0}(1907)$

Comment: whoops, 1905 was a typo.