# When does the busy beaver function surpass TREE(n)?

Tags: trees, turing-machines, upper-lower-bounds, big-numbers

Since TREE is a computable function the BB function grows faster than it, but TREE seems to grow much more quickly early on, so when does Busy Beaver surpass it?

Comment: We don't know when it passes it, the largest value we know is $BB(4) = 13$. Furthermore $TREE(n)$ is so unfathomable large it is likely we cannot prove when they cross.

Comment: @packetpacket Can one not make a reasonable guess at when it roughly passes it?

Comment: $TREE(n)$ is known to be a computable function. Therefore let $m$ be the number of states in a 2-color Turing machine, such that the Turing machine can compute $TREE(n)$. We now have $BB(m) \geq TREE(m)$ and certainly $BB(m+1) > TREE(m+1)$. So an upper bound to where they cross can be found by finding the minimum number of states required to compute $TREE(n)$

Comment: It would be nice to give a lnik to [TREE sequence](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/TREE_sequence).

Comment: This question seems somewhat related to [MSE question 723286](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/723286/) "Milton Green's lower bounds of the busy beaver function".

Comment: It would seem that we have $$\Sigma(3350)>\operatorname{TREE}(n)$$for reasonably small $n$, thanks to @Somos 's link. A tighter bound may come from $$\Sigma(81,10)>f_{\text{BHO}}(2050)$$ where $\text{BHO}$ is the Bachmann-Howard ordinal, though I'm not familiar with how to convert this to the single argument $\Sigma$.

Comment: Related claim by [Friedman](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2006-March/010279.html): "TREE(3) is greater than the halting time of any Turing machine initialized with a blank tape, which can be proved to halt in $\text{ACA}_0+\Pi^1_2\text{-BI}$ by a proof with at most $2^{1000}$ symbols."

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not have an upper bound for $\Sigma(n)$ for any $n\ge 5$ , it would be interesting, when $TREE(3)$ is surpassed. Is $\Sigma(200)$ sufficient ?